# django makemigration not detecting field addition to existing model but detects model additions

Tags: django, django-models

git diff shows

`+ best_img_path = models.CharField(max_length=255)`
for models.py

But makemigrations says **No changes detected**

However on adding a new model makemigrations detects changes.

Any ideas?

FYI, I'm on django 2.0 with mysql

Comment: Is the app the model is defined in included in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: In addition to @umgelurgel's answer do, `./manage.py makemigrations <app_name>`